# How to sort and group on column using pandas loop

Tags: python, pandas, loops, sorting, group

from a data frame
df1 =

| Area | Sequence | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 604582.25 | 320710 |
| A | 1 | 604590.25 | 320704.75 |
| A | 3 | 604579.25 | 320710 |
| B | 2 | 536584.47 | 176977.83 |
| B | 1 | 536570 | 176996.43 |
| C | 1 | 509202.13 | 307995.99 |
| C | 2 | 509205.3 | 307951.24 |

Need to generate into

df1 =

| Area | XY_by_sequence |
| --- | --- |
| A | 604590.25 320704.75 , 604582.25 320710 , 604579.25 320710 |
| B | 536570 176996.43 , 536584.47 176977.83 |
| C | 509202.13 307995.99 , 509205.3 307951.24 |

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```py
x = (
    df.set_index(["Area", "Sequence"])
    .stack()
    .groupby(level=[0, 1])
    .agg(lambda x: " ".join(map(str, x)))
    .groupby(level=0)
    .agg(", ".join)
    .reset_index(name="XY_by_sequence")
)
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
  Area                                               XY_by_sequence
0    A  604590.25 320704.75, 604582.25 320710.0, 604579.25 320710.0
1    B                      536570.0 176996.43, 536584.47 176977.83
2    C                      509202.13 307995.99, 509205.3 307951.24
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution:

```
(df.sort_values(['Area', 'Sequence'])
 .assign(XY=df['X'].astype('str') + ' ' + df['Y'].astype('str'))
 .groupby('Area')['XY'].agg(lambda g: ', '.join(g))
 .reset_index())
```

Output:

```
  Area                                                 XY
0    A  604590.25 320704.75, 604582.25 320710.0, 60457...
1    B            536570.0 176996.43, 536584.47 176977.83
2    C            509202.13 307995.99, 509205.3 307951.24
```

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing (if you know how many groups you'll have), is creating N groups, and defining their start and end. Then, you'd have to create a new table where you'd add a row each time the value in Area changes. Another way is simply this :

```
import pandas

value = df['Area'].iloc[0]

string a =""
#generate new table with a first blank row
for row in df.iterrows():
    if(row['Area']==value):
        a+ = row['X']+" "+row['Y']+","
        #add a to your newly created table in the row you generated
        a = ""
    else :
        value= row['Area']
        #generate new row
        a+ = row['X']+" "+row['Y']+","
        #add a to your newly created table in the row you generated
        a = ""
```

N.B : The comments are for things you'll have to do yourself